# Digital Signature uses private key for encryption, and public key for decryption?

Tags: encryption, certificates, cryptography, digital-signature, asymmetric

Public key is for encryption, and private key is for decryption in PKIs.
And digital signature employs the PKIs.
How to use a private key for encryption, and using public key for decryption which violate asymmetric cryptography?

**from geeksforgeeks**
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/digital-signatures-certificates/

> The steps followed in creating digital signature are :
>
> 1. Message digest is computed by applying hash function on the message and then **message digest is encrypted using private key of sender to
>    form the digital signature.** (digital signature = encryption (private
>    key of sender, message digest) and message digest = message digest
>    algorithm(message)).
> 2. Digital signature is then transmitted with the message.(message + digital signature is transmitted)
> 3. **Receiver decrypts the digital signature using the public key of sender.**(This assures authenticity,as only sender has his private key
>    so only sender can encrypt using his private key which can thus be
>    decrypted by sender’s public key).
> 4. The receiver now has the message digest.
> 5. The receiver can compute the message digest from the message (actual message is sent with the digital signature).
> 6. The message digest computed by receiver and the message digest (got by decryption on digital signature) need to be same for ensuring
>    integrity.

Comment: "message digest is encrypted using private key of sender" -- this is wrong, but it is a common misconception. Signing *uses* the private key as part of the process.

Comment: This has been discussed about a hundred times already; see my (incomplete!) list at https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/159282#159289